# flex measuredHeight vs height

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Could anyone tell me what the difference between height and measuredHeight is in flex?

After reading a few articles on the adobe site, I'm still non the wiser as to when to use which.

Any pointer much appreciated;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of measuredHeight usually applies to skins applied to UI components.

measuredHeight is the default height as specified by a skin for a UI component. height is the actual height the component currently has and can be manipulated.

A quote from the URL attached below:

> The measuredWidth and measuredHeight getters typically return a constant number. The Flex application usually honors the measured sizes, but not always. If these getters are omitted, the values of measuredWidth and measuredHeight are set to the default value of 0.

Take a look at this (examples included):
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinning_6.html

Comment: Thanks lior. I'm wondering what height to record when trying to save the state of a uicomponent on the stage to the db with a view to reconstructing that state when the user reenters the app.

Comment: You should store the height value.